# C# Manually added dataset, how to retrieve data to text columns

Tags: c#, tableadapter

I have added a dataset to the solution (Windows Form) by "Add"-> New item ->DataSet & created a new tableadapter query that fetches **desired data against passed parameter** in the design time.

Now I want to assign the data filled in the tableadapter to few textboxes while a button is clicked.

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer specific to my situation. I am not sure whether it is the best or the standard, as I am not getting much help with searches, I am accepting my own finding as a solution.

```
private void getnameid2()
        {
            PersonDataSet newPersonDataSet = new PersonDataSet(); //PersonDataSet is the manually created dataset
            PersonDataSetTableAdapters.L_PEOPLETableAdapter newPersonDataSetTableAdapter = new PersonDataSetTableAdapters.L_PEOPLETableAdapter(); 

            DataTable mytable = new DataTable();
            mytable = newPersonDataSetTableAdapter.GetData(decimal.Parse(this.civilidTextbox.Text.ToString()));
//foreach (DataRow row in newPersonDataSetTableAdapter.GetData(decimal.Parse(this.civilidTextbox.Text.ToString()))
            foreach (DataRow row in mytable.Rows)
            {

                nameTextBox.Text = row["FIRST_NAME"].ToString();
                personidTextBox.Text = row["PERSON_ID"].ToString();
            }

            // if (mytable.Rows.Count > 0) { MessageBox.Show(mytable.Rows.Count.ToString()); }

        }
```

Now I am calling the procedure while cell is validating to avoid the already saved transactions being updated while browsing the records, I am checking the transaction id column and calling a return to avoid.

Hope this helps someone else out there or brings the attention of experts who can device better approach :)